# Merge Two Arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, merge

Suppose I have two arrays, array1 and array2, that look like

array1

```
        45    46   47    48    49    50
        1.0   1.5  1.3   1.2   0.9   1.1
```

array2

```
        45    46   47    48    49    50
        2.5   5.5  4.5   5.8   1.5   8.4
```

and I want to merge them into a data frame that looks like:

```
       1.0  2.5
       1.5  5.5
       1.3  4.5
       1.2  5.8
       0.9  1.5
       1.1  8.4
```

The numbers 45 to 50 don't matter.

Comment: Can you `dput` your arrays so we're not guessing as to the actual structure of your objects?

Comment: Have we answered your question?

Answer (score 12):

```
 array1 <- c(1.0,1.5,1.3,1.2,0.9,1.1)
 array2 <- c(2.5,5.5,4.5,5.8,1.5,8.4)

 result = cbind(array1, array2)
```

In case you don't want to see any column names or row names (as posted in your question), you should do the following:

```
 result = as.matrix(cbind(array1, array2)) 
 dimnames(result) <-list(rep("", dim(result)[1]), rep("", dim(result)[2]))
```

You get:

```
 > result

  1.0 2.5
  1.5 5.5
  1.3 4.5
  1.2 5.8
  0.9 1.5
  1.1 8.4
```

Comment: `as.matrix(cbind(...))` is pretty redundant here, isn't it? The default `cbind` method is to create a `matrix`. There is a separate method for `data.frame`s, but that doesn't get called in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine `?rbind` and `?t`, or just use `?cbind` depending on the format of your data.

For example:

```
new.array <- t(rbind(array1,array2))
```

or

```
new.array <- cbind(array1,array2)
```

or

```
new.arrray <- data.frame(array1,array2)
```

If you have two vectors, `cbind` is the best way to go. However, suppose you have two data frames. ie:

```
array1 <- t(data.frame(array1=c(1.0,1.5,1.3,1.2,0.9,1.1)))
array2 <- t(data.frame(array2=c(2.5,5.5,4.5,5.8,1.5,8.4)))
```

Using `cbind` will not give the desired output, and you will need to combine `t` and `rbind`.

```
> cbind(array1,array2)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
array1    1  1.5  1.3  1.2  0.9  1.1  2.5  5.5  4.5   5.8   1.5   8.4

> t(rbind(array1,array2))
     array1 array2
[1,]    1.0    2.5
[2,]    1.5    5.5
[3,]    1.3    4.5
[4,]    1.2    5.8
[5,]    0.9    1.5
[6,]    1.1    8.4
```

Answer (score -3):

**You can merge to arrays by below given code and can display in required format.**

```
            for (int i = 45; i <=50; i++)
            {

                float[] merge = { array1[i], array2[i] };

            }
           // to display in required format

            for (int j =0; i <merge.Length; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(merge[i]);

            }
```

Comment: I believe by the tag the OP was looking for a solution using r.

Comment: See the tag `R` the question is about R.